# Remove inner contours within a larger contour using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following image that has either black or purple pixels that represent the output of a road image segmentation. As you can see the outline of the road is well defined (may not look it but it is) however there are some areas within the road that are showing up as black instead of purple.

[image: Original image to process]

I've been trying to apply different things to "smooth" it out but haven't found a way to do that. So i tried applying contours and that gives me the outside contour just fine and lots of smaller embedded contours if you will. I'm trying to figure a way to remove all the "black" areas within the outer contour.

Here is the image with contours applied - ideally i'd keep the outter contour and replace everything within it with the purple color. I have a feeling this is easy but not finding it...

[image: IMage with contours applied]

Comment: OpenCV allows to extract a hierarchy during contour extraction.it is a bit complicated to use, but probably you can google for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

after some more searching found its a supported part of the findContours method...using mode RETR_EXTERNAL

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I hade to make the bottom row of pixels purple to close the contour but this worked for me.